# how to build an android browser that only show webpage and without menus or any buttons

Tags: mobile, browser

I have build an responsive website with mobile menu .

So, I want to creat build an android browser that show my website in phones without app menu or any thing like buttons or bars that comes with apps, just my Web page in full screen and it's has a menu and all .

So, I want a way to build it with my zero experience of android development.

I know that is many websites that offer building a free app for your website but it still has a menus like ( about as ,setting, etc... ) .

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to actually understand you question but have you taken a look at Cordova?
It allow to build an apk from a single page website.
There are plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: I will search about Cordova but it's not my target .